# SpecReporter is not a constructor error on jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-spec-reporter

I try to configure simple project on jasmine using node.js. I got following files:

```
/*global jasmine */
 var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        '**/*.testdev.ts'
     ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'foo',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
     beforeLaunch: function() {
         require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e'
             });
        },
    onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
    }
};
```

Then a test file:

```
import {} from 'jasmine';
describe ("test", function() {
  it ("should work", function() {
      console.log('============ Main Workflow file starts');
  });
});
```

And I receive error when I'm running `npm test`:

```
C:\newcheckproject>npm test

> newcheck@1.0.0 test C:\\newcheckproject
> protractor

(node:7492) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[12:47:12] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:47:12] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[12:47:15] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: SpecReporter is not a constructor
at onPrepare (C:\Users\OSP\WebstormProjects\newcheckproject\protractor.conf.js:30:38)
at q_1.Promise (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\util.ts:48:39)
at Function.promise (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\util.ts:39:10)
at plugins_.onPrepare.then (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:103:21)
at _fulfilled (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
at runSingle (C:\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[12:47:15] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

All answers says that I should replace in the protractor file a line: `var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');`, but I do have it. What might also a problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [3.0.0](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300), jasmine-spec-reporter module exports SpecReporter and DisplayProcessor.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/tree/master/examples/node#use-jasmine-spec-reporter-with-node), you need to configure it like this:

```
const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
```

Comment: The documentation says that I should create a new `spec/helpers/reporter.js` file, with the content containing your answer. How can I use it in protractor, if I can't use `import` in it? Replacing `var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');` with `const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;` and adding/replacing the `onPrepare` function does not work (the errors are `Unable to compile TypeScript` or `ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined`

Comment: There is also a working [protractor exemple](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/tree/master/examples/protractor) in the repository. My guess is that you need to update your protractor configuration with `framework: 'jasmine2',`.

Comment: Yup, there was a mess in all json files also, needed time to clean it up according to documentation, but now everything seems to be working. Thanks! :)